# Deriving the expression for average marginal effects in a logistic model with dummy variables?

Tags: regression, logistic, marginal-effect

To calculate average marginal effects in a logistic model we take the average of the logistic p.d.f for all the values of X in the sample and multiply by the coefficient $b_j$, such that $d\;Pr(y=1)/d\;x_j=b_j E[\text{logistic p.d.f(X B)}]$ (note d is a partial derivative).

But this is for continuous variables. What expression do I use if I have dummy variables in the model?